# Android Support Library Minimum SDK

Tags: android, compatibility, android-support-library

What is the minimum SDK version for the **Android Support Library** (also known as the compatibility library?  Does it go all the way back to SDK 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most items in the Android Support package support back to API Level 4 (a.k.a., Android 1.6).

Answer (score 1):

The Minimum API level supported: 4

You can see more information over here:

> http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html